# Getting "Error loading data" in Job running monitoring page on AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I am getting "Error loading data" in Job run monitoring page on AWS Glue. I can able to see the data when I logged in as "Admin" user but I cannot see the data while I am logging in as "role" user. Do we need to add any specific permission to see the job monitoring data in Role policy.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Answer (score 1):

Your IAM role should have `glue:UseGlueStudio` permission.